# Kafka producer/consumer can't connect to broker other than localhost:9092 using Spring Boot 3.1.5

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot 3.1.5 and Kafka 3.0.12, trying to build an application exactly from the sample at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka.
When I enable the listener for my topic, with local kafka in docker, it works well.
But after moving Kafka to another computer, I get the following error on the consumer:

**[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-testGrp-1, groupId=testGrp] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.**

In the project - there is no set local address: 127.0.0.1,
**I don't understand: why the app does not use setted address 172.16.16.15 ?**

The application properties are very simple:

```
server.port=8081
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=172.16.16.15:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.groupid=testGrp
long.message.topic.name=longMessage
greeting.topic.name=greeting
filtered.topic.name=filtered
partitioned.topic.name=partitioned
multi.type.topic.name=multitype
test.topic=testtopic1
spring.jmx.enabled=true
```

Here's the Consumer method.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${test.topic}")
public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) {
    LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", consumerRecord.toString());

    payload = consumerRecord.toString();
    latch.countDown();
}
```

in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

and plugin with repackage for easi started from command line:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.baeldung.kafka.embedded.KafkaProducerConsumerApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: From IDE works well. This error only from command line: 
jdk-17.0.2/bin/java -jar spring-kafka-expl-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=application.properties

Comment: When you provide `spring.config.location`, where does the `application.properties` come from? It doesn't look like it is reading the correct configuration. This is why when running the application, it defaults to `localhost:9092`.

Comment: Kafka also returns its own set of servers that your app actually connects to. Bootstrapping is a two step process https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you!  I think, your comment points to the root cause!
 Indeed, tests have shown that this is the behavior only when connecting Kafka to a test instance of Kafka 172.16.16.15, deployed in Docker without fine-tuning!
At the same time, when connecting to the real instance 172.16.16.16, there were no calls to the localhost address. (the behavior was correct)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve, need to set, on Kafka side, advertised.listeners (or KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS if you’re using Docker images) to the external address (host/IP) so that clients can correctly connect to it.

My docker-compose file set is incorrect for my case **localhost** address:

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```

Details [here in short helpfull article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/).

Thank you a lot @OneCricketeer for the helpful comment! And link to article.